# Using org-mode for writing. Would like text in quotes to be highlighted and also character names

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

I'm using org-mode to write a novel and I would like to have any text between "quotes" to be a different color, just to be able to easily see when a character is talking.

Also, if I could have a list of names (in document) that are character names, and have those names highlighted too that would be awesome. Bonus if I can click them to go to a (in document) description of them.

Comment: I think you can do this with the button-lock package. See http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/06/26/Clickable-text-for-learning-environments/ for an example of using it. You can define one button for quoted text, and another one for the names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`font-lock-add-keywords`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords) function to add keywords to any face you like, in any mode. In fact, the keywords are regular expressions, so quotes are also possible:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(
  ("Herbert" 'org-warning)
  ("Caesar" 'org-warning)
  ("\"[^\"]*\"" . 'org-ellipsis)
  ("«[^»]*»" . 'org-ellipsis)
))
```

Multi-line quotes may behave somewhat strange, though, especially the non-paired quotes (" and '), as opposed to paired ones (e.g. «guillemots»).

To find suitable faces for your keywords, you can use M-x `customize-faces`.